# PHP Header() function not redirecting

Tags: php, redirect

I've got a problem with the header function

```
if ( ! isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {

   header('Location: login.php');

}
```

There is no echo before the if, the page is empty!

it doesn't redirect me. I've `var_dump();`'ed something in the If statement and it worked so the if is correct.

The php version is 5.6

Comment: Do you have any error ? Is there anything echoed before ?

Comment: Nothing echoed before

Comment: 1. Do you enter the `if`-statement? 2. Do you have *any* kind of output before this? Headers has to be called before *any* output is made to the browser (whitespace, HTML-coding, `echo` from PHP).

Comment: any output or HTML before the header function could make it fail. Also a so called Byte Order Mark (BOM) could let it fail.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: turn on error reporting and set display_errors on 1 then if there are errors probably because you have sent some output to browser like white char then fix it

Comment: There was a whitespace indeed..

Comment: I guess your problem is because headers are already sent. you must print a javascript window.location.href='/login.php' to redirect to login.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have outputted something to the browser before header call. First check:

- is there any html before php opening tag
- is there any whitespace before php opening tag
- is another php script included with echo before that script
- is the coding utf8 with BOM?

Those are possible reasons of your error.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :-

```
<?php
if ( ! isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
?>
<script>
    window.location = 'login.php';
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: @Floes Take a look at the answer @n-dru posted instead. Most likely your `header` isn't working because of charset encoding, or having some kind of output before the `header` is called. This solution isn't optimal, as it won't work if JavaScript is disabled in the browser. Also, always remember to use `exit;` after calling a redirect, to stop the rest of the script from executing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do following:

```php
echo "<script>window.location = 'login.php';</script>";
```

Answer (score -1):

white space may cause the redirect
change it to something like

```
if ( ! isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {

   header('location:login.php');

 }
```

Comment: That really doesn't matter, the issue is most likely either a session not started or output before the `header` is called. (Not my downvote btw).

Comment: the session not started is true, there is no output before the header

Comment: @Floes Post your all page code so that it get's clear to everyone